# 3rd monitor showing "X" cursor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have 2 GPUs and 3 monitors. The NVIDIA settings shows all 3 monitors but the Displays panel only shows 2 and `xrandr` only shows 2 connected. See below:

[image]

[image]

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04
   1600x1200     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00    50.08
   720x480       59.94    60.05
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
DVI-I-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04
   1600x1200     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00    50.08
   720x480       59.94    60.05
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Unfortunately I can't take a screen shot of the cursor issue but in simplest terms when I move my mouse to my 3rd monitor it changes from a pointer to a black "X" with a white outline.

I have tried changing driver versions and a handful of other things but nothing seems to work, I have a feeling I'm missing something simple.

I have also played around with my xorg.conf file a bit but I keep breaking things in there and having to revert so I just let `nvidia-xconfig` deal with the file for me.

Here are my relevant system specs:

- GPU: 2x GTX 580 Classified LC
- Current Driver Version: NVIDIA 364.19 (I have tried the 367, 370, and 361 drivers). The standard X.Org X Server driver causes cursor lag issues but works for all 3 monitors.

Comment: in nvidia x server settings, try going to advanced and enabling 'basic mosaic'. That did it for me