# 3rd Monitor Not Visible, showing 'X' cursor - Dual GeForce GT 1030 and Triple Benq Monitors Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, gpu

So i bought 2 GeForce GT 1030 cards and want to run 3 monitors on them simultaneously. 2 are connected via HDMI and DVI respectively on the first graphics card. These are the only two that show up in the output of xrandr.Additionally only the 2 monitors on the first graphics card show ubuntu on the screen.

The fact that both the graphics cards are the same model and 2 of the screens are the same model is probably not helping.

```
  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
  DVI-D-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 399mm
     2560x1440     59.95*+
     1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
     1680x1050     59.95  
     1600x900      60.00  
     1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
     1280x800      59.81  
     1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
     1024x768      75.03    60.00  
     800x600       75.00    60.32  
     720x576       50.00  
     720x480       59.94  
     640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
  HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
     1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
     1680x1050     59.95  
     1600x900      60.00  
     1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
     1280x800      59.81  
     1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
     1024x768      75.03    60.00  
     800x600       75.00    60.32  
     720x576       50.00  
     720x480       59.94  
     640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Nvidia-settings is able to see them, however it is not possible to put them on the same xscreen it seems. Or use xinerama.

[image: screenshot]

The problem is somewhat similar to t this - [3rd monitor showing "X" cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843561/3rd-monitor-showing-x-cursor) however i can't get the X cursor to show up on the third screen, its staying lit green, but no input.

Also attached is my xorg.conf, generated by nvidia-settings.

## nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings

```
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.64


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 4480 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ PD3200Q"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 90.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ GW2470"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
    BusID          "PCI:45:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 1030"
    BusID          "PCI:35:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
# Removed Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+360 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try basic troubleshooting methods- change the 3rd screen to the HDMI/DVI port which was working. Power cycle TV and CPU (yank their cable and hold the power button for 1 min, then plug it back in).

Additionally seeing the problem arises when using 2 GPU's simoultaneously, I would highly recommend you try to use either integrated graphics of CPU or use a single card and test/experiment it out

Comment: So all ports are working. The issue is the xorg config it seems. All screens work when switched, both cards appear to be working and the screen is visible in nvidia-settings.